# Conditional Formatting on cell values

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm currently trying to set conditional formatting on an excel document. I'm currently using interop to work with the document.

The column contains time/date values and I'm trying to create a condition that highlights values over 15 minutes.

This is what I've got so far.

```
range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("F2", "F" + RC);
Excel.FormatCondition condition = (Excel.FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(
        XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, 
        Type.Missing,
        "> =0,0104166666666667",
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing);

condition.Interior.ColorIndex = 3; // Red
```

The range selects the correct column, I think the issue is i'm not building the right formula.

[image: Conditional formatting in excel]

This is what the condinonal formatting looks like when I do it in excel.

[image: What my formatting looks like]

This is what my formula looks like when I try replicate it with my application.

```
   ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    Range("F1:F11").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="=0,0104166666666667"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

This is the macro equivalent of what I'm trying to do in C#.

Comment: In my opinion, the second paramter shouldnt be Type.Missing but ``XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater`` and the third Parameter should  only be ``=0,0104166666666667`` without the greater sign. Did you try record macro?

Comment: I've done what you said and now it's highlighted the entire column, No I haven't tried that. I will look it up quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Excel.FormatCondition condition = (Excel.FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreater, "=0,0104166666666667", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Changing Formula conditions to xlCellValue did the trick.